# Couldn't find Generator without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the results of all generators and results merge them into 1 table.
I have the following association :

Generator has_many: results
Result belongs_to:generators

Whenever i want to create a new results , i got an error saying couldn't find Generator without an ID. Why do i get the error ? How should i fix it ?

For example : localhost:3000/generators/new = is the part where i entered my values into the generator form and after clicking create button , it'll bring me to localhost:3000/generators/8/results/new. It is here after keying in values for this form , i get the error message saying Couldn't find Generator without an ID . I'm trying to have a page whereby i can display both Generators + Result values together. SHow all generators and their respective results data in 1 page.

## GeneratorController

```
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all(:include => [:results])
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
      if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
          @generator.random_generate(generator_params)
      elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'
          @generator.no_ATGC(params[:no_A],params[:no_T],params[:no_G],params[:no_C])
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
          @generator.seating(params[:user_seq])
      end

    @generator.result_choice=params[:result_choice]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
          if @generator.result_choice == 'Yes'
            format.html { redirect_to(new_generator_result_path(@generator)) }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
          end
      else 
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length,:choice,:random_primer_generated,:no_A,:no_T,:no_G,:no_C,:user_seq)
    end
end
```

## Result.rb

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator, foreign_key: "generator_id"

    def generate_result(result_params)
    ref_seq = self.ncbi_ref_seq
    Bio::NCBI.default_email = "spykix@hotmail.com"
    fasta_sequence = Bio::NCBI::REST::EFetch.nucleotide(ref_seq,"fasta")
    fasta=Bio::FastaFormat.new(fasta_sequence)
    self.genome_seq = fasta.data
    self.genome_sample = fasta.definition    

    g=Generator.last
    p=self.genome_seq.scan(g.c_primer)
    self.binding_times= p.length()      
  end

end
```

## ResultController [ the error is highlighting at the line for def create ;   generator = Generator.find(params[:id]) ]

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_result, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /results
  # GET /results.json
  def index
    @results = Result.all
  end

  # GET /results/1
  # GET /results/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /results/new
  def new
    @result = Result.new
  end

  # GET /results/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /results
  # POST /results.json
  def create
    @result = Result.new
    @result = @result.generate_result(result_params)
    generator = Generator.find(params[:id]) 
    @result = generator.results.build(result_params)

   # generator = Generator.find(3)
  #  @result = generator.results.build(result_params) 
   # @result=@result.generate_result(result_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @result }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /results/1
  # PATCH/PUT /results/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.update(result_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /results/1
  # DELETE /results/1.json
  def destroy
    @result.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to results_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_result
      @result = Result.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def result_params
      params.require(:result).permit(:ncbi_ref_seq)
    end
end
```

## generator/index.html.erb

```
<h1>[Index]Random Amplified Polymorphic DNA [RAPD] Primer Generator</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primer length</th>
      <th>Selected choice</th>
      <th>Random primer generated</th>
      <th>Complimentary primer</th>
      <th>NCBI ref seq</th>
      <th>Genome sample</th>
      <th>Binding times</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
     <% @generators.each do |generator| %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= generator.primer_length %></td>
        <td><%= generator.choice %></td>
        <td><%= generator.random_primer_generated %></td>
        <td><%= generator.c_primer %></td>

        <% for result in generator.results %>
        <td><%= result.ncbi_ref_seq %></td>
        <td><%= result.genome_sample %></td>
        <td><%= result.binding_times %></td>
        <%end%> 

        <td><%= link_to 'Show', generator %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_generator_path(generator) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', generator, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
<%= link_to 'New Generator', new_generator_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If generator have many results, than First you should find generator in new method, because when you create any record, it initializes from the new method. I am rewriting you new and create methods, you can take reference from it:

```
def new
 generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
 @result = generator.results.build(result_params)     
end

# POST /results
# POST /results.json
def create    
  @result = @result.generate_result(result_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @result.save
      format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @result }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: hi i followed ur steps but i still get an error Couldn't find Generator without an ID. Below are my codes 

`def new
     generator = Generator.find(params[:generator])
    @result = generator.results.build(result_params) 
  end`